# How can I access the one board in JIRA Agile via the JSON REST API?

Tags: json, api, rest, jira, agile

If I want to access JIRA Agile's One Board via the JIRA JSON API, how do I go about that?

Is there one place I can query to find out what the swim lanes are, and another place I can get information about tickets that will include data that determine what swim lanes they are in?

How much of the JIRA API is available programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the REST Browser plugin and the jira-python library which shows how to use some of the JIRA Agile REST API

Comment: Thank you. Will that turn up information that is transferable to iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following REST api to get all Boards.

> GET /rest/agile/1.0/board

And then to get one board of your choice, you can use this :

> GET /rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}

Here is the link for [JIRA Agile](https://docs.atlassian.com/greenhopper/REST/cloud/)